# how can i give one part of flex div bigger size?

Tags: css

i have a div where info is inserted

```
<div class="inputs">
    <div class="content">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => invoices.ProductDesc, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })</div>
    <div class="content">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => invoices.ProductSKU, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })</div>
    <div class="content">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => invoices.ProductQuantity, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })</div>
    <div class="content">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => invoices.ProductUnit, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })</div>
    <div class="content">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => invoices.IsMilled, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })</div>
    <div class="content">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => invoices.ProductUnitPrice, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })</div>
</div>
```

i use display: flex to show them nicely, however display flex seems to only be able to spread the width for each column to the same size evenly. I need more space for my first div (ProductDesc)

how can i either give that 1st div bigger width or  wrap the info in that product desc div to go to 2nd line when it exceed the width of the div?

i have tried break word

```
.content {
flex: 1 1 10%;
overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

i have also tried other various settings of overflow but none seems to give what i want

also no i cant change these into table. im assuming because of how the data is pulled and for mobile purposes

full code snippet

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
        <div class="inputs">
            <div class="title">@Html.Label("Description:ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff ")</div>
            <div class="title">@Html.Label("SKU: ")</div>
            <div class="title">@Html.Label("QTY: ")</div>
            <div class="title">@Html.Label("Unit: ")</div>
            <div class="title">@Html.Label("Milled: ")</div>
            <div class="title">@Html.Label("Unit Price: ")</div>
        </div>


        if (Model.InvoicesDetails.Count > 0)
        {
            var invoices = Model.InvoicesDetails[1];

            for (int i = 0; i < Model.InvoicesDetails.Count; i++)
            {

<div class="inputs">
    <div class="content">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => invoices.ProductDesc, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })</div>
    <div class="content">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => invoices.ProductSKU, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })</div>
    <div class="content">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => invoices.ProductQuantity, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })</div>
    <div class="content">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => invoices.ProductUnit, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })</div>
    <div class="content">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => invoices.IsMilled, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })</div>
    <div class="content">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => invoices.ProductUnitPrice, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })</div>
</div>





                /*<div class="inputs">
                   @/*Html.Label("ProductLinePrice: ")
                   @/*Html.TextBoxFor(model => invoices.ProductLinePrice, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
               </div>*/

            }

        }

        else
        {
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            @Html.Label("No Records Available for the year selected.")
        }
        @*</div>*@
    }
</div>
```

Comment: `.content:first-child { flex: 2 1 10%; }`?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what u r expecting:

use `flex-wrap` to wrap the content and u can also specify required width in the flex property.

Syntax:  `flex: flex-grow | flex-shrink | flex-basis ;`

flex-basis- value for width.

if you want to break all words u can use `word-break:break-all;`

```css
.inputs {
  display: flex;
}

.content:first-child {
  background:lightblue;
  flex: 0 0 250px;  /* u can specify the width based on u r requirement*/
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.content {
  background: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputs">
  <div class="content">1 content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content     </div>
  <div class="content">2</div>
  <div class="content">3</div>
  <div class="content">4</div>
  <div class="content">5</div>


</div>
```

Comment: that is exactly what im expecting but i put that exact css in and my content still got cutoff / it wont overflow :(

Comment: sorry but i guess i forgot to mention there is a 2nd div as "title" but that probably wont change much. i edited full code snippet @Amaresh

Comment: just try word-break:break-all css property @wswswswsws

Comment: that didnt change anything :( @Aamaresh

Comment: could u please create fiddle it will help us to clearly understand what is going on there. please a create a fiddle and add all css whatever u have used @wswswswsws

Answer (score 0):

Just leave the width as `auto` on the first child elements (don't apply any flex values). The others can have `flex:1`.

```css
.inputs {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: .25em;
}

.content:not(:first-child) {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputs">
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Asperiores, aliquid. Lorem ipsum dolor sit emet</div>
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum </div>
  <div class="content">Lorem </div>
</div>
```